# Bash: Inserting one file's content into another file after the pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to write a bash script, which will do the following:

1. reads the content from the first file (as a first argument)
2. reads the content from the second file (as a second argument)
3. finds the line in the second file with the given pattern (as a third argument)
4. inserts text from the first file to the second file after the line of the pattern.
5. prints final file on the screen.

For example:

first_file.txt:

```
111111
1111
11
1
```

second_file.txt:

```
122221
2222
22
2
```

pattern:

```
2222
```

output:

```
122221
111111
1111
11
1
2222
111111
1111
11
1
22
2
```

What should I use to realize this functionality on BASH?

I wrote the code, but it doesn't work properly (why?):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    first_filename="$1"
    second_filename="$2"
    pattern="$3"

    while read -r line
    do
    if [[ $line=˜$pattern ]]; then
            while read -r line2
            do
                    echo $line2
            done < $second_filename
    fi
    echo $line
    done < $first_filename
```

Comment: For the 4th point, `sed -i 'line, text...'` can make it

Comment: could you give a small example? (input and expected output)

Comment: What happens in your current code? "Doesn't work" is not a very good error description

Comment: @Emil Vikstrom: My code just output first_filename's content in each line of the second_filename. It's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need spaces around the `=~` operator. Compare:

```
[[ foo=~bar ]]
[[ foo =~ bar ]]
```

This is because the first expression essentially evaluates as "Is this string empty?"

Also, the **OP code uses [small tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02dc/index.htm) rather than [tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007e/index.htm)**.

Even so, you can easily get rid of the inner loop. Just replace the whole `while read -r line2` bit with `cat -- "$second_filename"`.

Your last `echo $line` is only correct if the file does *not* end in a newline character (standard with *nix tools). Instead, you should use `while read -r line || [[ $line ~= '' ]]`. This works with or without newline at the end.

Also, [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices).

Comment: ./replace_shell.sh: line 9: conditional binary operator expected
    ./replace_shell.sh: line 9: syntax error near `=˜'
    ./replace_shell.sh: line 9: ` if [[ $line =˜ $pattern ]]; then'

Comment: And when I tried to do: "cat -- "$second_filename": I've got an error: sed: 1: "file2.txt": invalid command code f

Comment: @user2431907 `=˜` is not the same as `=~`. `˜` is [Unicode Small Tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02dc/index.htm).

Comment: @user2431907 `sed`? There's no `sed` command in your original code. You'd better post the *actual code* if you want help with it.

Answer (score 49):

`sed` can do that without loops. Use its `r` command:

```
sed -e '/pattern/rFILE1' FILE2
```

Test session:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)" 
$ printf '%s\n' 'nuts' 'bolts' > first_file.txt
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo' 'bar' 'baz' > second_file.txt
$ sed -e '/bar/r./first_file.txt' second_file.txt
foo
bar
nuts
bolts
baz
```

Comment: +1 Never heard of the `r` command. Added a test session to verify.

Comment: Is there some way to ensure it's only inserted once?

Comment: @l0b0 `sed -e '1,/pattern/rFILE1' FILE2` will insert it only once but there is an edge case where `pattern` occurs on the first line. In that case use GNU sed: `sed '0,/pattern/rFILE1' FILE2`

Comment: @l0b0 @potong: Or, use branching: `sed -e '/pattern/{ r FILE1' -e 'b R' -e '}' -e 'b' -e ':R {n ; b R' -e '}' FILE2`

Comment: @l0b0: Sort of, yes, but without ``sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'``

Comment: @l0b0: No, the point is `sed` sometimes needs a newline or a new expression.

Comment: For the "do it just once" request, sometimes `ed`, while more verbose, is clearer than sed: `printf "%s\n" '/2222/r first_file.txt' '1,$p' q | ed second_file.txt 2>/dev/null` -- to edit in-place, replace '1,$p' with 'w'

Answer (score 11):

Using ***awk*** works as well.

To insert before the ###marker### line :

```
// for each <line> of second_file.txt :
//   if <line> matches regexp ###marker###, outputs first_file.txt.
//   **without any condition :** print <line>
awk '/###marker###/ { system ( "cat first_file.txt" ) } \
     { print; } \' second_file.txt
```

To insert after the ###marker###line :

```
// for each <line> of second_file.txt :
//   **without any condition :** print <line>
//   if <line> matches regexp ###marker###, outputs first_file.txt.
awk '{ print; } \
     /###marker###/ { system ( "cat first_file.txt" ) } \' second_file.txt
```

To replace the ###marker### line :

```
// for each <line> of second_file.txt :
//   if <line> matches regexp ###marker###, outputs first_file.txt.
//   **else**, print <line>
awk '/###marker###/ { system ( "cat first_file.txt" ) } \
     !/###marker###/ { print; }' second_file.txt
```

If you want to do in-place replacement, use a temp file for being sure the pipe doesn't start before awk has read the entire file; add :

```
> second_file.txt.new
mv second_file.txt{.new,}
// (like "mv second_file.txt.new second_file.txt", but shorter to type !)
```

If you want replacement inside of the line, (replacing just the pattern and keeping the rest of the line), a similar solution should be achievable with ***sed*** instead of ***awk***.

Comment: this works a treat when your variable has any quotes in it, sed can't really deal with that

Comment: My awk solution (replacing marker):
awk -v f="$file"  '/###marker###/  {system("cat " f); next}; 1' -- where $file, the file to insert, must not have spaces in it's name :/

Answer (score 4):

I use sed like this and it worked as a charm

***sed -i -e '/pattern/r filetoinsert' filetobeinserted***

What it does is insert the 'filetoinsert' into 'filetobeinserted' after the line with the specified pattern

Take care to choose a unique pattern, not sure how it will work with a duplicate patterns, I assume it will do it just of the first one

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{open(A,"first_file.txt");@f=<A>;}print;if(/2222/){print @f}' second_file.txt
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
111111
1111
11
1
> cat temp2
122221
2222
22
2
> perl -lne 'BEGIN{open(A,"temp");@f=<A>;}print;if(/2222/){print @f}' temp2
122221
111111
1111
11
1

2222
111111
1111
11
1

22
2
>
```